# Updating a nested document mongo. Concurrency issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling with a seemingly basic issue in Mongoose.

I have a method that looks like so:

```
changeStateOnIncident: function(req, res, next) {
  Incident.findOneQ({ _id: req.params.id })
  .then(function(incident) {
    if (!incident) { return next(new restify.ResourceNotFoundError("Incident with id " + req.params.id + " not found.")) }
    return incident.addStateChange(req.body)
    .then(function(savedState) {
      return res.json(201, savedState);
    })
    .then(function() {
      var alertOrders = _.map(incident.alertees, function(alertee) {
        return alertee.createAndSendAlert(req.body)
      })
      return Q.allSettled(alertOrders)
      .then(function(results) {
        return incident.save();
      })
    })
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    return next(new restify.InvalidContentError(JSON.stringify(err)))
  })
},
```

As for createAndSendAlert and addStateChange, their definitions are [here](https://gist.github.com/dbousamra/743c86322c00f540831e)

What I am trying to do here is as follows:

1. Find the Incident matching the ID passed in.
2. Add the state event to the array of state changes.
3. Return that newly added change event back to the user.
4. For every alertee on the Incident, loop through and add an alert to that alertees list of alerts, the result of an SMS request.
5. Save that incident.

Unfortunately, the way I'm doing it now is failing for concurrent writes. Suppose I send two

```
{
  _id: "53cc87d0feeb4302007eadbe",
  alertees: [
    {
      _id: "eJ65nfJh_g",
      alerts: [
        {
          "_id": "53cc87d1feeb4302007eadc1",
          "created_at": "2014-07-21T03:24:01.304Z",
          "response": "Sent",
          "state": "First state change",
          "updated_at": "2014-07-21T03:24:06.802Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "53cc87d2feeb4302007eadc5",
          "created_at": "2014-07-21T03:24:02.348Z",
          "response": "Sent",
          "state": "Emergency",
          "updated_at": "2014-07-21T03:24:06.802Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "53cc87d6feeb4302007eadcc",
          "response": "Sent"
          "state": "Ended",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  states: [
    {
      _id: "53cc87d1feeb4302007eadbf",
      state: "First state change"
    },
    {
      _id: "53cc87d1feeb4302007eadc2",
      state: "Second state change"
    },
    {
      _id: "53cc87d2feeb4302007eadc4",
      state: "Third state change"
    },
    {
      _id: "53cc87d6feeb4302007eadcb",
      state: "Fourth state change"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think what is happening is IF I send two states  A and B. And A's SMS response comes back before B's it will possibly invalidate the document B is trying to modify. I am losing changes to the sub document if state changes are sent too close to each other.

Any idea? How could I rewrite this? Using update methods perhaps?

Comment: The nested arrays are the source of your problem here as you cannot send an atomic update. That is a basic thing that is not supported in MongoDB. Ideally you need to model around this and remove the need for nested arrays. Can the alertees move out to separate documents? Just looking for ways to remove one level of arrays.

Comment: It is possible to separate alertees out, but I'd prefer not to. So, what, alertees would be an array of alertee Id's?

Comment: Your concurrency issue is largely in these steps A. Load item, B. Modify item in app memory C. Send back to server where possibly already changed. To avoid that you want to update to the server in one request, just the update only. The problem is posted in the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator update documentation. So ideally you avoid having arrays nested within other arrays. With separate docucuments, the "multi" parameter of `.update()` might be of use.